# Files under /home in singularity container are not accessible

Tags: singularity-container

Could someone please let me know how one can access files in `/home` within a singularity container?

I created a docker image. In this image, some packages are built and installed under `/home`. Some of those are also added to `PYTHONPATH` within the docker image. If I run the image, then a docker container is created. Within this container I can access all files under `/home` and use the Python modules that I added. This is a fully working docker image.

I wanted to use the packages and Python modules on a HPC system. So, I converted the docker image to a singularity image. Then, I used the `singularity shell <image_name.sif>` command to access the shell in the container. After that I see the  prompt below.

```
Singularity> cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
Singularity>
```

The host OS on the HPC system is Red Hat Linux. Since the `/etc/*-release` command shows Ubuntu, it seems like the `/etc` directory is the one inside the container. This looks reasonable. However, when I type `ls /home`, then I see the contents of `/home` on the host OS. Howe could I find the files in `/home` within the container?

If I type any commands to run the packages installed in `/home` within the container, then the singularity shell prints `command not found`. Also, if I run the Python interpreter, then I cannot import any modules installed within the container. Although the Python version matches the one in the container, the modules are not located. The `PYTHONPATH` includes paths like  `/home/<a_directory_name>`, but the Python interpreter cannot locate the modules. Even though the docker image is fully functional, the corresponding singularity image is completely useless.

How could I use the packages and Python modules installed in `/home` in the singularity container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [Singularity automatically mounts `$HOME`](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/quick_start.html#working-with-files) into the container, which will shadow anything that was installed there during image creation.

To skip this, use the [`--no-home`](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#no-home) flag when running your singularity command. Additional options, such as mounting home to a different location, are described in the online and CLI documentation.